# RangeSlider in android generating a lots of thumbs

Tags: android, slider, rangeslider

When creating a range slider with only two points, on thumb position change, it shows all the older thumbs. Looks like mosses or some kind of grass grown up on the slider.

I expect to fix the rendering issue that is producing such erroneous results.

Comment: can you share the code and result image?